# filter results from Rails ActiveRecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you filter results returned from an active record collection? I'm not trying to delete from the Article table just trying to filter results for each user based upon the permissions of each article.

I could use a where clause `@articles.where(some condition)` I believe but I have to check the privacy_level for each article and apply additional filters based on the different privacy levels so I'm not sure if that would work.

```
          @articles = Article.includes(:user, :country, :favorites)
                          .where(is_deleted: false)
                          .where("articles.organization_id is null OR articles.organization_id = #{@authenticated_user.organization.id}")
                          .filter(filter_items)
                          .order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
                          .paginate(page: params[:page])


          @articles.each do |article|

            if article.privacy_level == 0 and article.user_id != @authenticated_user.id
              # @articles.delete_at(article.id)
            end

            if article.privacy_level == 1 and article.organization_id != @authenticated_user.organization.id
               # remove from results
            end
          end
```

Comment: Not really following your question - what do you want to happen if the privacy level is 0 and 1 respectively? They both look like t hey remove the article from the @articles collection

Comment: I want to remove an article form the @articles collection if certain conditions are met.  yes both if statements should remove articles.  Not sure how to remove them from the collection.

Comment: possibly I need to just add each article that meets a certain condition to an array and return that to the index action?

Comment: Use a second call to `where`. The database should be used for filtering. Also with paginated result you will filter in the returned page, which will return odd results.

Comment: @mbuechmann yes I tried that but ran into a problem because there are going to be 4 different privacy levels.  So I would need something like `.where("#{@authenticated_user.id} = articles.user_id") if privacy_level == 0` I'm not sure how to handle that conditional if statement for each of the 4 different privacy_levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a bit of logic to deal with in the controller. I'd suggest adding to your article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  def self.articles_for_list(authenticated_user)
    where(privacy_level: 0).where.not(user_id: authenticated_user.id).or(
      where(privacy_level: 1).where.not(organization_id: authenticated_user.organization.id)
    )
  end
end
```

I think that's how you want to add them to the list but I'm not sure. Then in your controller:

```
@articles = Article.includes(:user, :country, :favorites)
                          .articles_for_list(@authenticated_user)
                          .where(is_deleted: false)
                          .where("articles.organization_id is null OR articles.organization_id = #{@authenticated_user.organization.id}")
                          .filter(filter_items)
                          .order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
                          .paginate(page: params[:page])
```

EDIT:

Uglier version for rails 3+ :

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  def self.articles_for_list(authenticated_user)
    ids_1 = where(privacy_level: 0).where.not(user_id: authenticated_user.id).collect(&:id)
    ids_2 = where(privacy_level: 1).where.not(organization_id: authenticated_user.organization.id).collect(&:id)
    where(id: (ids_1 + ids_2))
  end
end
```

Comment: this is the cleaner way to do it

Comment: thanks for this answer.  I'm on Rails 4.2.4 though and I'm getting `undefined method or` looks like this would work great on Rails 5.  I just have to figure out whatever the Rails 4 workaround is to get `or` working.

Comment: No probs! You can extract quite a bit more of that code out into the controller but at least it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You've already got this guy filtering your articles:

```
.where("articles.organization_id is null OR articles.organization_id = #{@authenticated_user.organization.id}")
```

which should already filter out the articles in your first condition (it filters out all articles where the organization_id doesn't match the authenticated user's organization):

```
article.privacy_level == 0 and article.user_id != @authenticated_user.id
```

So you could add another where clause to the active record query for the second `if` condition:

```
.where('article.privacy_level != 0 or article.user_id == ?', @authenticated_user.id)
```

**Side note**: generally, you don't want to use string interpolation in SQL query strings as it leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

So you might want to change your first `where` to something like:

```
.where("articles.organization_id is null OR articles.organization_id = ?", @authenticated_user.organization.id)
```

Check out the [rails security guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the info about the SQL Injection attack, I updated my query.